# I encrypt empty folder with cipher but it show that it is not encrypted

Tags: batch-file, encryption, terminal

I encrypt empty folder with this from terminal ot bat file:

```
set Folder="%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Fold PAC"

Cipher /e /s:"%Folder%"
```

but when I check poperties of the folder, the property "Encrypt contents to secure data" is not active. How do I encrypt the folder>

Comment: The command line syntax, available by `ENTER`ing `cipher /?` at the Command Prompt, shows `CIPHER /E /S:directory [pathname [...]]` Where is your `pathname`? _it is supposed to be `a pattern, file or directory`_. What is the expanded value of `%Folder%`? and How was that variable defined? We expect here a [mcve] of your code, and sufficient information about your environment, and for instance, before and after information, in order that we can replicate your issue. Please use the [edit] facility, in order to supply us with those details. Thank you.

Comment: The first thing I'd advise is that you learn how to define a variable. The recommended method is this: `Set "VariableName=StringValue"`. So because you've not done that, this is what your command looks like `Cipher /e /s:""C:\Users\Vladimir\Documents\Fold PAC""`. There are too many doublequotes there, and as such you may need to try to understand exactly how `%SystemRoot%\System32\cipher.exe` handles quoting of its arguments. Better safe than sorry, and change your `set` command to `Set "Folder=%UserProfile%\Documents\Fold PAC"`